# Why doesn't Guava RateLimiter limit for too large permits per second anymore?

Tags: java, limit, guava, rate-limiting

I'm uploading some data using some HTTP lib to some web service and need to limit the amount of data uploaded per second. The used limiter is [Guava RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html), pretty much following the second example limiting some data stream. Two differences for me: I'm providing some `InputStream` to the consumer and am using `aquire` in the [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())-method providing one byte at a time only. No packets of different size or such ever, which from my understanding should make things easier. Additionally, my permits per second are larger than the example.

Things seemed to work pretty well for low numbers, but doesn't for higher ones and there's exactly one number at which things start to not work anymore. I'm limiting in terms of KiB/s and everything up to and including `1 * 1024 * 976` works, but with `977` things start to fail and the limit doesn't seem to be applied anymore. This can easily be seen using some network monitor, the first config limits upload ~7-8 MBit/s, while the latter raises up to 60 or more, depending on how the outgoing interface is used otherwise and such. From my understanding the increase in upload should be much smaller, 1 KiB/s only and therefore not notable at all.

I'm able to reproduce the problem using the following code:

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(1 * 1024 * 976);
        RateLimiter msgLimiter  = RateLimiter.create(1);
        long        aquired     = 0L;

        while (true)
        {
            rateLimiter.acquire();
            ++aquired;

            if (msgLimiter.tryAcquire())
            {
                System.out.println(
                    String.format(  "Aquired: %d MBit/s",
                                    (aquired * 8) / (1024 * 1024)));
                aquired = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results with `976`:

```
Aquired: 0 MBit/s
Aquired: 7 MBit/s
Aquired: 7 MBit/s
Aquired: 7 MBit/s
Aquired: 7 MBit/s
```

Results with `977`:

```
Aquired: 0 MBit/s
Aquired: 77 MBit/s
Aquired: 85 MBit/s
Aquired: 82 MBit/s
Aquired: 83 MBit/s
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

I've already read about the "downsides" of RateLimiter regarding [bursts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/UST-DM5BMAo) and such, but don't see if and how this explains my problem.

The problem doesn't occur using a [TimedSemaphore](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/TimedSemaphore.html):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.TimedSemaphore;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        int             rateLimit   = 1 * 1024 * 2000;
        //RateLimiter   rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(rateLimit);
        TimedSemaphore  rateLimiter = new TimedSemaphore(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, rateLimit);
        RateLimiter     msgLimiter  = RateLimiter.create(1);
        long            aquired     = 0L;

        while (true)
        {
            rateLimiter.acquire();
            ++aquired;

            if (msgLimiter.tryAcquire())
            {
                System.out.println(
                    String.format(  "Aquired: %d MBit/s",
                                    (aquired * 8) / (1024 * 1024)));
                aquired = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results with `976` are the same as before, so higher values are of more interest:

```
Aquired: 0 MBit/s
Aquired: 15 MBit/s
Aquired: 15 MBit/s
Aquired: 15 MBit/s
Aquired: 15 MBit/s
```

Comment: Same here. Could be a race condition because of the high aquire rate. Increase the aquire block size and everything works as expected again.

Comment: As I don't have any control about the size of the blocks requested, don't I suffer from all the downsides `RateLimiter` has in this case? Initially granting very large blocks, not being able to equally distribute work for individual large blocks over time etc. If all requested blocks are of size 1 MB, I won't get 1 KiB/s stable upload, but only higher bursts. That's why I thought limiting at the lowest possible value should be preferred. Which means preferring `TimedSemaphore` because of this strange behaviour? Or should one simply assume reasonable large blocks of 4 or 8 kb only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Guava RateLimiter can only work up to a limit of 1,000,000 aquire calls per second. If you try to do 1,000,001 aquire calls per second the call to `aquire` will not wait at all (return value of `aquire()` is always 0.0) -> no throttling occurs.

Therefore the following scenarios work as expected:

`RateLimiter.create(1000000l);` // this will work when using `aquire()` / `aquire(1)`

`RateLimiter.create(100000000l);` // this will work when using `aquire(100)` or higher.

Assuming that typical network traffic is never received byte-by-byte but in blocks of 100-1000 bytes the Guava RateLimiter would work up to a limit of 100,000,000 (~762 MBit) to 1,000,000,000 (7.45 GBit/s) bytes per second.

If those values would be sufficient for your project you can stick with Guava RateLimiter. If not I would recommend to use the Apache TimedSemaphore instead.

Comment: I could live with those values, but especially regarding the contract of `InputStream`: Users are allowed to read packets of and individual bytes, because those methods are public. To force applying limits, am I not forced to limit in `read` for individual bytes? Or do you think that in my use case of uploading stuff this simply won't happen and can therefore be ignored as only a theoretical problem?

Comment: From my understanding an upload via InputStream works the way that the http lib (on client side) reads the data to be uploaded. Therefore the only chance to get data only byte by byte would be to use an InputStream implementation that only reads one byte. Or is your question about a rate limit on server side?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know how likely it is in your opinion that some HTTP lib reads individual bytes for some reason, bypassing my rate-limit this way then. I guess it's pretty unlikely.